# How do I delete from a SQLite database in python using a tkinter entry instead of stating a string or value?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to delete a row in my SQLite database using the following lines:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()
memID = str(idBox.get())
#c.execute('DELETE FROM Test WHERE memberID = idBox.get()')
```

so i am trying to delete from the table using a tkinter entry (idBox) but get the following error:

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1699, in **call**
    return self.func(*args)
  File "I:/Onedrive/PycharmProjects/TKinter/MainProgram/main.py", line 36, in delete_data_entry
    c.execute('DELETE FROM Test WHERE memberID = idBox.get()')
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

I have been stuck with this for quite some time and would appreciate some help

more code (memberid variable being created):

```
memberid = str(uuid.uuid4())
print(memberid[0:8])
c.execute("INSERT INTO Test(memberID, fullname, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
          (memberid[0:8], fullnameBox.get(), usernameBox.get(), passwordBox.get()))
conn.commit()
```

Comment: did u try just putting a value like 5 to see if it works staticly?

Comment: Have you tried `c.execute('DELETE FROM Test WHERE memberID = ' + memID)` ?

Comment: Gave it a try and got this: ' Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "I:/Onedrive/PycharmProjects/TKinter/MainProgram/main.py", line 36, in delete_data_entry
    c.execute('DELETE FROM Test WHERE memberID = ' + memID)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token: "44ba195d" '

Comment: that value is definitely in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering comment from @Philip Blonde and syntax

```
c.execute('DELETE FROM Test WHERE memberID = ' + memID)
```

the problem is that you are passing `44ba195d` as `memberID` and sqlite is expecting something else, maybe an integer. This

```
DELETE FROM Test WHERE memberID = 44ba195d
```

will result in if memberID shall be an integer

> OperationalError: unrecognited token "44ba195d"

Check what you are getting from `idBox`.

**EDIT:** Since you're using `uuid` as a memberId, you have to change SQL statement to

```
c.execute("DELETE FROM Test WHERE memberID = '" + memID + "'")
```

If the data type is not an integer it must be in quotes.

**WARNING:** Keep in mind that these SQL sentences are vulnerable to SQL injection. You should never use string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. One could input `' OR memberID LIKE '%1%` and delete all rows where memberID includes value 1.

Comment: "memberid = str(uuid.uuid4())" that is how i am creating the member ID so from the start I am converting it to a string. Are you saying I should be leaving it as an integer?

Comment: I assumed that memberID is an integer, because it normally is. One thing is for sure, sqlite is expecting something else. What is the data type and length of memberID column? Maybe open database and execute that delete query there.

Comment: I edited my answer with changed syntax. Since memberID is not an integer, it must be in quotes.

Comment: hold on let me edit the question ad add more code. I kind of understand what you are saying but I am very new to SQLite

Comment: oh okay I'll give it a try

Comment: I have added a bit more code so that you could see the memmberid variable being created

Comment: The code didn't work it just returns an empty list like it couldn't find the member ID?

Comment: Print out memID and compare it to the one in database. It should work if both are the same.

Comment: they are exactly the same?

Comment: Make sure you commit deletion after execution with `conn.commit()`

Comment: No problem. Keep in mind that you should never use string concatenation (+) as in this example or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. It's vulnerable to SQL Injection. I suggest you look into that once you get the basics down.